# I have blazor & web api containers. I am using docker-compose up with the docker-compose.yml file. I tried to deploy into Azure, but it is not working

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, blazor, webapi

I have blazor & web api containers. I am using docker-compose up with the docker-compose.yml file. I tried to deploy into Azure, but it is not working.

What I did was that I made each blazor & web assembly as a container then uploaded into my docker hub. Then, put ‘image:’ into my docker-compose.yml file in order to use in the Azure.
Here is my file:
[image]

Since when I deploy, Azure give me a url with https, I also changed my nginx.config for my blazor to be like this:
[image]

Then, I tried again by giving – port:80 and – port: 443 for the wasm container. However, it did not work.
After deploying it by this process:
[image]

[image]

It gives me an error (I thought it will map to my blazor web, but it isn’t).

[image]

Why it is not working??